# Has anyone an idea how this weird output of my C program occurs?

Tags: c, arrays, queue, output

I do not understand, why the following C-code leads to the following output.

I want to program an array-queue and what I have done allready is to write the function "enqueue_fct" which adds new elements to the queue and "loops" the array.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 5

int enqueue_fct (int newElem_e, int * array_e, int last_e)
    {
    array_e [last_e] = newElem_e;
    last_e = (last_e + 1) % MAX;
    return (last_e);
    }

int main (void)
    {
    int newElem = 0;
    int array [MAX];
    int last = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
    last = enqueue_fct (newElem++, array, last);
    printf ("array[%d] --> %d\n", last, array [last]);
    fflush (stdout);
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

Output:

```
array[1] --> 0
array[2] --> -13210
array[3] --> 0
array[4] --> 0
array[0] --> 0
array[1] --> 1
array[2] --> 2
array[3] --> 3
array[4] --> 4
array[0] --> 5
array[1] --> 6
array[2] --> 7
array[3] --> 8
array[4] --> 9
array[0] --> 10
array[1] --> 11
array[2] --> 12
array[3] --> 13
array[4] --> 14
array[0] --> 15
```

From the fifth line on the output is what i expected, but what about the first four lines? I do not mean, why it does not start with "array[0]", it is clear why this is the case. But I do not get, where the "0, -13210, 0, 0" comes from, before the correct output starts with the second "loop" of the array.

I am a beginner, so if there is a very stupid mistake in the code, be lenient with me and please try to explain in simple words a beginner can understand ;-)

Thank you very much for your help!

P. S.: 
I am using Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) with newest cygwin gcc compiler on Windows 10 64bit.

**EDIT:**

Because of 2501s answer I corrected my code and added a **-1** to the printf statement.

```
printf ("array[%d] --> %d\n", last, array [last-1]);
```

Now there is another problem in the output, which I do not understand:

```
array[1] --> 0
array[2] --> 1
array[3] --> 2
array[4] --> 3
array[0] --> 1
array[1] --> 5
array[2] --> 6
array[3] --> 7
array[4] --> 8
array[0] --> 1
array[1] --> 10
array[2] --> 11
array[3] --> 12
array[4] --> 13
array[0] --> 1
array[1] --> 15
array[2] --> 16
array[3] --> 17
array[4] --> 18
array[0] --> 1
```

Why is array[0] always '1' and not '4', '9', '14', '19'? Sorry, as I said, I'm a beginner...

**EDIT2:**

I've got it by myself: When 'last' becomes '0' at the beginning of a loop "array [last-1]" is "array [-1]", which is not part of the array, so the '1' ist junk-data.

Everyone starts as complete programming noob ;-)

Comment: unrelated .. you don't need the `fflush (stdout);`. `printf` is line-buffered, so when it sees a `\n` character (which you have) it flushes its buffer to `stdout`.

Comment: Thank you, yano, for the info. Does it lower performance, when I add fflush (stdout) where it is not necessary?

Comment: hmm, good question. You'd have to check the generated assembly, but I suspect yes, adding `fflush(stdout);` here would add extra (unnecessary) instructions and thus lower performace. I don't _think_ the compiler would optimize that out (even if it looked at the `printf` string and saw the `'\n'` at the end, it would have to be sure nothing else had written to `stdout` by that time). But I'm just thinking out loud, somebody smarter than me will need to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not printing the element that was just assigned to the array, but the next one. When printf is called the variable last indexes the next element.

In the first MAX loops you print uninitialized elements of the array, and in subsequent loops, you print the values that were assigned in the previous MAX loops.

Comment: O. k., that was an stupid mistake... Thank you! Can not give you an upvote, because of my low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you update the value of `last` before you print the result.

```
last = enqueue_fct (newElem++, array, last);
printf ("array[%d] --> %d\n", last, array [last]);
fflush (stdout);
```

`enqueue_fct` returns the index value of the next element in the array (rolling over at the end of the array). You are using this value to print the element that was just assigned, however after `enqueue_fct` returns, it points at the next element.

For example, after calling `enqueue_fct` for the first time with `last=0`, it assigns `last=1`. Then you print `array[last]` which is the second element of the array, not the first.Since the array is uninitialized, you'll get garbage out.

Comment: Thank you (Can not give you an upvote, because of my low reputation), I have corrected this mistake, but now I have another problem (see my edit of first post). Do you have a solution for that, too?

Comment: I've got it by myself, why this happened (see EDIT2).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean this:

```
int main (void)
{
    int newElem = 0;
    int array [MAX];
    int last = 0;
    int i, newlast;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        newlast = enqueue_fct (newElem++, array, last);
        printf ("array[%d] --> %d\n", last, array [last]);
        last = newlast;
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Thank you (Can not give you an upvote, because of my low reputation), I have corrected this mistake, but now I have another problem (see my edit of first post). Do you have a solution for that, too?

Comment: No, no, the statement « printf ("array[%d] --> %d\n", last, array [last-1]); » makes no sense; keep it this way: array[last] but add the variable newlast as I told you.

Comment: Yes, [last-1] was my own try, after the answer of the user 2501, which solved my first problem but caused a new one. After that, I tried your answer and it works fine and stays this way in my program, thanks. But I'm still interested, why the [last-1] causes the '1' at each array[0]. Can you tell me?

Comment: Without my modification, your [last - 1] would work only if you change in a consistent way both parameters of the printf function in this way: « printf ("array[%d] --> %d\n", last - 1, array [last-1]); »

Comment: No, this change makes no difference in relation to the problem, that at every output of array[0] the result is '1' and not '4', '9', '14', '19', like I would expect. It's a complete mystery for me, why this happens.

Comment: I've got it by myself, why this happened (see EDIT2).